# How to return gaps in numbers stored as char with leading zeros?

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with a char(5) field for tracking Bin Numbers. The numbers are stored with leading zeros. The numbers go from 00200 through 90000. There are a lot of gaps in the numbers already in use and I need to be able to query them out so the user knows which numbers are available to use.

Comment: Sounds like it might be two issues. Have you searched for `gaps` and `zero fill`? Do you have an attempt that didn't work?

Comment: The correct fix is to start storing them as integers, and format with the leading zeros when you retrieve the data.

Comment: @HABO, Thanks for the tip. After searching for `gaps` I found a great article and was able to come up with a great solution. I really don't see how changing to an integer is a solution to the question. It may be best practice but the issue still remains that I need a way to find `gaps` in a sequence regardless of the data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get exactly what I needed by reading this [article by Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/06/sql-server-find-gaps-in-the-sequence/)

I created a stored procedure that returned the gaps in the bin number sequence starting from the first bin number to the last. In my application I group the bin numbers by Shop (Vehicles would be 1000 through 2000, Buildings 2001 through 3000, etc).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSelectLOG_BinsAvailable]

(@Shop varchar(9))
AS
BEGIN
declare @start as varchar(5) = (SELECT b.Start FROM BinShopCodeBlocks b WHERE b.Shop = @Shop)
declare @finish as varchar(5) = (SELECT b.Finish FROM BinShopCodeBlocks b WHERE b.Shop = @Shop)

SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH CTE 
AS
(SELECT
        CAST(@Start as int) as start,
        cast(@Finish as int) as finish

UNION ALL
SELECT
        Start + 1,
        Finish

FROM
        CTE
WHERE
        Start < Finish
)

SELECT
    RIGHT('00000' + CAST(Start AS VARCHAR(5)), 5)
FROM CTE  
WHERE
NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT *
         FROM
         BinMaster b
         WHERE
         b.BinNumber  = RIGHT('00000' + CAST(Start AS VARCHAR(5)), 5)
        )
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);


END
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a table of valid bin numbers.

```
Table: bins

bin_num
--
00200
00201
00202
...
90000
```

Assume your table is named "inventory". The bin numbers returned by this query are the ones that *aren't* in "inventory".

```
select bins.bin_num
from bins
left join inventory t2
       on bins.bin_num = t2.bin_num
where t2.bin_num is null
order by bins.bin_num
```

If your version of SQL Server supports analytic functions (and, solely for convenience, common table expressions), you can find *most* of the gaps like this.

```
with bin_and_next_bin as (
  select bin, lead(bin) over (order by bin) next_bin
  from inventory
)
select bin
from bin_and_next_bin 
where cast(bin as integer) <> cast(next_bin as integer) - 1
```

Analytic functions don't require a table of valid bin numbers, although you can make a *really* strong case that you *ought* to have such a table in the first place. If you're working in an environment where you don't have such a table, and you're not allowed to *build* such a table, a common table expression can save the day. (It doesn't show "missing" bin numbers *before* the first used bin number, though, as it's written here.)

One other disadvantage of this statement is that the WHERE clause isn't sargable; it can't use an index. Yet another is that it assumes bin numbers can be cast to integer. The table-based approach doesn't assume anything about the value or data type of the bin number; it works just as well with mixed alphanumerics as it does with integers or anything else.